Cannot resolve method 'addCallback' in 'CompletableFuture'
I have the following Kafka client which I want to migrate to Spring Boot 3:
@Service
public class KafkaProducer<K, V> {
  
  private final KafkaTemplate<K, V> kafkaTemplate;

  public KafkaProducer(KafkaTemplate<K, V> kafkaTemplate) {
    this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
  }

  public void send(String topic, K key, V message, ListenableFutureCallback callback) {
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, message);
    if (Objects.nonNull(callback)) {
      future.addCallback(callback);
    }
  }
}

I get an error:
Required type: ListenableFuture <SendResult<K, V>> 
Provided: CompletableFuture <SendResult<K, V>>

I changed the code to:
CompletableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, message);
    if (Objects.nonNull(callback)) {
      future.addCallback(callback);
    }

But now I get:
Cannot resolve method 'addCallback' in 'CompletableFuture'

Do you know what should be the proper way to migrate this code?

The JavaDoc of ListenableFutureCallback is clear:

Deprecated.
as of 6.0, in favor of CompletableFuture.whenComplete(BiConsumer)

public void send(String topic, K key, V message, BiConsumer<SendResult<K, V>, Throwable> callback) {
    CompletableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, message);
    if (Objects.nonNull(callback)) {
        future.whenComplete(callback);
    }
}

It is a bit cumbersome, so I suggest defining this:
public interface Callback<K, V> extends BiConsumer<SendResult<K, V>, Throwable> {
}

public void send(String topic, K key, V message, Callback<K, V> callback) {
...
}


I need to use import java.util.function.BiConsumer;?

Yes. Yes. Yes...

I need to ask one more question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78316505/cannot-find-required-type-biconsumer Above code is used by this second question. But for some reason I get error.

About this comment It is a bit cumbersome, so I suggest defining this: Can you extend the answer a little bit, please?
