Cannot find Required type: BiConsumer
I want to migrate this Java code to Spring Boot 3:
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

public void send(String topic, K key, V message, BiConsumer<SendResult<K, V>, Throwable> callback) {
    CompletableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, message);
    if (Objects.nonNull(callback)) {
      future.whenComplete(callback);
    }
  }
......

// call kafka method
kafkaProducer().send("topic", "key",
        "messge", listenableFutureCallback("12345"));

......
    
    private ListenableFutureCallback listenableFutureCallback(String userId) {
        return new ListenableFutureCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            .......
          }
    
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(Object result) {
            ........
          }
        };
      }

I get error at this line: listenableFutureCallback("12345")
Cannot find required type
Required type: BiConsumer <org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,
java.lang.Throwable>
Provided: ListenableFutureCallback

Do you know how should I migrate/replace ListenableFutureCallback in order to return BiConsumer from listenableFutureCallback Java method?

Clearly ListenableFutureCallback does not extend, or resemble, BiConsumder <org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>, java.lang.Throwable>. So make it do that.

You can update the implemenation of callback like this:
import org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

public void send(String topic, String key, String message, BiConsumer<SendResult<K, V>, Throwable> callback) {
    CompletableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, message);
    if (Objects.nonNull(callback)) {
        future.whenComplete(callback);
    }
}

// call kafka method
void test() {
    send("topic", "key",
            "messge", listenableFutureCallback("12345"));
}


public BiConsumer<SendResult<K, V>, Throwable> listenableFutureCallback(String userId) {
    return new BiConsumer<SendResult<K,V>, Throwable>() {

        @Override
        public void accept(SendResult<K, V> kvSendResult, Throwable throwable) {
            if (null != throwable) {
                // same flow as of onFailure
            } else {
                // onSuccess flow
            }
        }
    };
}


I am using import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

Sorry, my bad. Didn't notice that. Have updated the answer. This implementation of BiConsumer can be used as a callback. Remember to update the return type to BiConsumer<SendResult<K,V>, Throwable> as well. Thanks.

hm... I get Cannot resolve symbol 'V'. Can you paste the complete code please?

Sure, have updated it. For the error, you are mentioning, please re-verify if the class is defined with the generics K and V i.e. public class SpringBootApplication<K, V>. Hope it helps!
