Required type: BiConsumer <? super org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,
I have this kafka code which I want to migrate to Spring Boot 3:
public void publishMessage(String message) {

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);

    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
        .....
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        ......
      }
    });
  }

I tried to change it this way:
public void publishMessage(String message) {

    CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);

    future.whenComplete(new CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>>() {

      @Override
      public void accept(SendResult<String, String> kvSendResult, Throwable throwable) {
        if (null != throwable) {
          // same flow as of onFailure
        } else {
          // onSuccess flow
        }
      }
    });
  }

I get error:
Required type: BiConsumer <? super org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,
? super java.lang.Throwable>
Provided: anonymous CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>>

Do you know what method I need to override and implement the have the same code logic?
EDIT:
public void publishMessage(String message) {
    CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
    future.whenComplete((result, throwable) -> {
      if (throwable != null) {
        .......
      } else {
        .......
      }
    });
  }


According to the error, it expects a function of type func(SendResult,Throwable), whereas you are providing a CompletableFuture instance. Have you tried just providing the lambda version of the accept method?

no, can you show me  code example, please?

Something like future.whenComplete((kvSendResult,throwable) -> {accept function logic here})

I added example. Is this correct?

Yes go ahead and try this.

did the proposed solution work?

Yes, I found a solution.

Not the one i suggested?

no I use it and I extended it.

Provide the solution then

I added it into the EDIT part.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78316119/cannot-resolve-method-addcallback-in-completablefuture
